# LocalDate causes Data truncation: Incorrect date value

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, localdate

I am trying to build an application that handles user's inputs with different data types using mysql and jpa. When I run the application I get an error of "MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value:". I really need help in solving this problem and I already Made some reseach but I was not able to figure it out.
 I am using Date type in mysql and LocalDate type for my entity class. Is it possible?

This is my first entity class:

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "flight")
      public class Flight implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Integer flightId;
       private String flightName;
       private String Name;
       private LocalDate firstDate;
       private LocalDate lastDate;
```

Booking entity class:

```
       @Entity
       @Table(name="booking")
       public class Booking implements Serializable {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Integer reservationId;
       private String hotelRoomType;
       private double totalAmount;
```

Database tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `flight` (
    `flightId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `flightName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `firstDate` date NOT NULL,
    `lastDate` date NOT NULL,
```

Booking table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `booking` (
`reservationId` int NOT NULL,
`hotelRoomType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `totalAmount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
```

)

Error message:
        Exception

```
        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested 
        exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse 
        Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
        org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
        Internal Exception: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: 
        Incorrect date value:
        '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.
        Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x07\x03\x00\x00\x07\xE4\x03\x12x' for column 
       'lastDate' at row 1
```

Error Code: 1292

```
       Call: INSERT INTO flight (FLIGHTID, FLIGHTNAME,LASTDATE, NAME, FIRSTDATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
       bind => [5 parameters bound]
       Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.springmvc.jpa.booking.Flight@f0670cc)
       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Root Cause:

```
       javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence 
       Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
       Internal Exception: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: 
       Incorrect date value: 
       '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser
        \x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x07\x03\x00\x00\x07\xE4\x03\x12x' 
       for column 'lastDate' at row 1
```

Error Code: 1292

```
       Call: INSERT INTO flight (FLIGHTEID, FLIGHTNAME, LASTDATE, FLIGHTNAME, 
       FIRSTDATE) VALUES (?, ?, 
      ?, ?, ?, ?)
      bind => [5 parameters bound]
```

This is an image shows the EclipseLink that are available:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwZZR.png)

Comment: NOTE: you originally tagged [hibernate] as well, but according to error reporting you're actually using [eclipselink]. Please pay attention next time. Know what you're actually using. By the way, the error you faced basically boils down to that the java.time.LocalDate is not supported by the JPA provider you're using (EclipseLink thus). Try upgrading/replacing it.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I am new to these technologies. I appreciate  your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs you are using EclipseLink 2.5, that is the reference implementation (RI) of JPA 2.1 (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.5.php)

Suport for LocalDate and the other Java 8 time classes where added in JPA 2.2.

You should update to EclipseLink 2.7 that is the RI of JPA 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this dependency:

```
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
             <version>5.4.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```